# call the activity interface method onDrawerItemSelected(view,position) in fragment page

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface

I need to call the activity interface method onDrawerItemSelected(view,position) in fragment page.is it possible.anyone can help me with this.So that I can do a custom drawer in fragment page.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

@Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new UserProfileFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_discovery);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new SettingsActivity();
                title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new InboxRequestActivity();
                title = getString(R.string.title_discovery);
                break;
            case 3:

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

 }
```

**CustomFragment.java:**

```
 public class CustomFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener


  menu_btn_click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);





            }
        });
```

on clicking the menu_btn_click, I need to call the activity interface method onDrawerItemSelected(view,position) in fragment page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position)` method in your fragment and call it on your activity:

```
@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    listener.onDrawerItemSelected(view, position);
}
```

therefor you will need to pass the activity as `FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener` to the fragment (e.g. by an appropiate setter).

```
setListener(FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}
```